# Re-expressing the Schrodinger Equation as a first order expansion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, quantum-mechanics

I am reading an online text on quantum computing and the author expands and re-expresses the Schrodinger equation. I am not really sure as to the intermediate steps he used or what happened to the derivative when going from the first to second equation. Thanks in advance.

$$\frac{d} {dt} |ψ(t)>  =  −iH(t)|ψ(t)> $$

"re-express this equation, to first order in the infinitesimal quantity dt".

$$|ψ(t + dt)> = (I − iH(t)dt)|ψ(t)>$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a forward difference approximation for the derivative:

$$
\frac {d \psi}{dt} = \frac{\psi(t + dt) - \psi (t) }{ dt } $$

Here I am treating dt now as an infinitesimal. Insert this and solve for $\psi (t+dt) $.